# Using a JS and JSP function in submit form

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I have this JS function

The function is returns "/outstanding-appeals-nonstop16/insertForm"

```
function access(){   
   <% String insert = request.getParameter("insert"); %>
   var insert2="<%=insert%>";   
   return ("/outstanding-appeals-nonstop16/"  + insert2 + "/");  
}
```

In my form I have

```
<form:form commandName = "aNewForm" action =  "javascript:access()"  method ="POST">
</form:form>
```

`insertForm` is a method in the controller. If I put `action = "/outstanding-appeals-nonstop16/insertForm"` I get the result I am looking for. But I think the action is just calling the JS function instead of the value given from the JS function.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does. You either input /outstanding-appeals-nonstop16/insertForm in the action attribute:

```
<form:form commandName = "aNewForm" action =  "/outstanding-appeals-nonstop16/<%=insert%>"  method ="POST">
```

or perform the form submit programmatically in your js function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript here:

```
<form:form commandName = "aNewForm" action ="/outstanding-appeals-nonstop16/${param.insert}/"  method ="POST">
</form:form>
```

Here, `${param.insert}` is equivalent to `<%= request.getParameter("insert")%>`